# Laravel 5. how to achieve this?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
$stocks = StocksUnderMedication::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

The above code gets all the rows that are in "StocksUnderMedication" table.

```
$originals = Stock::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

The above code gets all the rows that are in "Stock" table.

I'm trying to get all the rows in the Stock table whose "tag_no" equals "tag" in StockUnderMedication table.

That is Stock table has tag_no field and StockUnderMedication  has tag field.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: The question's title needs to be reworded in order to reflect the actual question/problem. What you have now won't help in a (Stack/Google) search.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Read the Laravel documentation on Eloquent queries and relationships, and you may have more of an idea.

Comment: i just need to get the stocks whose tag_no = tag

Comment: please attach your your both table structure in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach( $stocks as $stock )            
            <tr>
              <td>{{    $stock->tag_no    }}</td>

              @foreach( $originals as$original  ) 
                @if(  $original->tag_no ==  $stock->tag_no )                       
                  <td>{{    $original->stock_type      }}</td> 
                @endif
              @endforeach             
              <td>{{    $stock->description   }}</td>              
            </tr>                         
          @endforeach
```

This code will solve the issue.
Use the above logic in your view page.
Just use nested foreach but idk if it is the best solution.But it works fine.

Comment: $originals = Stock::find('tag_no', $stocks->tag_no); will this give me the result i want?

Comment: no find method use with primary key you have to use where clause

Comment: $originals = Stock::where('tag_no',$stocks->tag_no)->get();

Comment: actually i wanted to print stock_type value of each stock...

Comment: I have solved my issue :) !